# Best way to optimize 30+ gb of image on the server

Tags: debian, image-optimization

I have about 30gb of images on my site, and I'd like to use imagemin or something like that on them. Downloading and uploading them back is obviously not an option. In addition to that, new images are being add every day.

I believe there's some sort of software I can run in the background that will watch over the folders and optimize images as they appears. Anyone faces similar task?

My server is Debian.

Comment: Are you using some CMS or frontend framework?

Comment: Yes, it's an OpenCart website

Comment: There should be extensions for OpenCart that automatically compresses news images (while allowing compression of existing ones too). Other than that, on the server end, inotify + convert isn't too difficult a task, probably 4-5 lines of code.

Comment: These images are added by a 3rd party plugin for Opencart.

Comment: @Reuben I've implemented the inotify + convert combo for a client and it's cool but it wasn't actually a walk in the park to install.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combination of `inotify` and `convert` (image-magick) perhaps?